# Injecting HTML into another page without CSS conflicts

Tags: html, css, conflict, code-injection

I'm using Javascript to inject some stylized HTML into another webpage (which has been crawled) and I'm trying to do it in a way that minimizes any conflicts with the CSS styles of the target page. I'm injecting a fixed-position `<div>` which floats cleanly on top of the target page.

So far, the approach I've taken is to create a unique CSS id (a kind of namespace) that first resets all imaginable styles and then applies its own styles:

```
/* reset */
#my-div {display: block; visibility: visible; margin: 0; padding: 0; ... etc}
/* my styles */
#my-div {margin: 10px 5px; ... etc}
```

However, the `<div>` contains text, links, images, so I'd be forced to do this for everything inside it and generate lots of CSS code. This is because the target page's own styles will come through otherwise and affect my injected HTML.

I *can* do this... but I'm wondering if someone knows of a smarter/simpler way I could protect my HTML/CSS from those of the target page.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is an iframe so that the styles of neither the iframe or the page effect each other. Overlaying will be trickier, however.

Comment: Yep, it's got to go right into the page on this occasion, I'm afraid. Can't do Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Uniquely naming your classes and id's seems like the best way to do it short of using an iframe. I don't really see another way around it. What I've seen some people do is to put a shortened namespace with a dash before any css i.e. "twc-topnav".